# Proper Way to define a hasManyThrough Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

i have 3 tables:

**User** model

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      column         |     type         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        id           |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Relations in model:

```
public function properties()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Property::class, user_id)
}

public function favourite_properties()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Property::class, FavouriteProperty::class, 'user_id', 'user_id')
}
```

**Property** model

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      column         |     type         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        id           |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        user_id      |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Relations in model:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id')
}
          
public function favourites()
{
   return $this->hasMany(FavouriteProperty::class, 'property_id')
}
```

**FavouriteProperty** model

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      column         |     type         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        id           |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        property_id  |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        user_id      |     uuid         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Relations in model:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id')
}
          
public function property()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Property::class, 'property_id')
}
```

I want to be able to access the user's favourite properties through the `FavouriteUser` model and paginate the result so far i have  been getting the empty data results with this query, there are 4 records in the table belonging to the `FavouriteUser` model for the current user but i dont think am doing it right:

```
$user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();
$properties = $user->favourite_properties()->paginate(9);

return $properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following Laravel's naming convention you don't have to specify the foreign keys as parameter. But if you do want to, here's how:

```
favourite_properties(){
return $this->hasManyThrough( 
FavouriteProperty::class, 
Property::class,
'user_id', //Foreign key on properties table
'property_id', //Foreign key on favourite_properties table
'id',  //Local key on users table
'id') //Local key on properties table
}
```

Laravels documentation with example: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work, throws error:
   ** SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
    'properties.property_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 
    `properties` inner join `favourite_properties` on `favourite_properties`.`id` = 
    `properties`.`property_id` where `favourite_properties`.`user_id` = 9126a635-3ceb- 
    4398-9a75-144501be159f)**

Comment: classes was also swapped, and I've missed that, I've edited the answer

Comment: thanks @Urudin i get the results now but it's returning the collection for the `FavouriteProperty` model instead of the `Properties` itself.

Comment: Well that's the point of hasManyThrough . If you want to get the favourites from user, you can go user->favourites, why should that return the Properties?